# Mercurial Merge Issue

Tags: mercurial

Here's what happened.

Original directory was cloned to create a feature.

Cloned directory was pushed to the original before the original committed its changes.

Original was then committed.

I didn't know how to get the changes from both merged together. Whatever I tried, just switched between the two. I could pick individual files to revert to, but I couldn't seem to get an actual merge going. Mercurial didn't seem to think a merge was needed.

Comment: What happens when you run `hg merge` ?

Comment: Was there an `update` before the changes/commits in the original clone?

Comment: @PaulS: No. Certain files were changed in both directories without any updating between them.

Comment: @DavidLevesque: a message like "No need to merge into current head". If I switch the revision, it says I can't merge into the current revision or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two heads in the same named branch, you just run `hg merge` to merge them.

If you are getting a message telling that there is nothing to merge, that means that you have only one head in that branch. You can check it with `hg heads`.

Either the branches were already merged, or they are in different named branches. If that's the case, you have to explicitly type the branch name to merge:

1. Go to the branch that will receive the changes: `hg update <branch>`
2. Tell mercurial to merge with the changes of the other branch: `hg merge <other_branch>`

Checking the graph is also a great help. You can do it with a GUI like TortoiseHg or in the terminal with the [GraphLog extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension/). I just can't work without a graphical view to check what is going on.